# Sequences containing infinitely many primes

Tags: number-theory

What are some interesting sequences that contain infinitely many primes?

If it takes form of a polynomial, Dirichlet's theorem answer the question completely for linear polynomial. What about polynomials of degree more than 1? Is there a known polynomial of degree more than 1 that contains infinitely many primes?

What about more complicated sequences like $2^n+3^n$, $n!+1$, etc?

Please provide examples that are as interesting as possible, accompanied with proofs (or reference to proofs) if not too difficult.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/77780/15660

Comment: [Bunyakovsky conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture)

Answer (score 3):

A polynomial formula for the primes (with 26 variables) was presented by Jones, J., Sato, D., Wada, H. and Wiens, D. (1976). Diophantine representation of the set of prime numbers. *American Mathematical Monthly*, *83*, 449-464.

The set of prime numbers is identical with the set of positive values taken on by the polynomial

$(k+2)(1-(wz+h+j-q)^2-((gk+2g+k+1)\cdot(h+j)+h-z)^2-(2n+p+q+z-e)^2-(16(k+1)^3\cdot(k+2)\cdot(n+1)^2+1-f^2)^2-(e^3\cdot(e+2)(a+1)^2+1-o^2)^2-((a^2-1)y^2+1-x^2)^2-(16r^2y^4(a^2-1)+1-u^2)^2-(((a+u^2(u^2-a))^2-1)\cdot(n+4dy)^2+1-(x+cu)^2)^2-(n+l+v-y)^2-((a^2-1)l^2+1-m^2)^2-(ai+k+1-l-i)^2-(p+l(a-n-1)+b(2an+2a-n^2-2n-2)-m)^2-(q+y(a-p-1)+s(2ap+2a-p^2-2p-2)-x)^2-(z+pl(a-p)+t(2ap-p^2-1)-pm)^2)$

as the variables range over the nonnegative integers.

Answer (score 1):

Look here

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MillsConstant.html

The formula is, unfortunately, of little practical value because the constant
must be known to tremendous many digits to produce $15-20$ primes, and the
sequence grwos too fast, but theoretically, it is beautiful.